# How to share a current user’s facebook profile

Tags: facebook, react-native, mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk

I’m building a react native app and I’d like the user to be able to share their facebook profile. Is there a way, using the facebook  api or sdk, to give another user a link to view someone else’s facebook profile?

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/#fields:

> `link`
> string
> A link to the person's Timeline. The link will only resolve if the person clicking the link is logged into Facebook and is a friend of the person whose profile is being viewed.

You’re gonna need `user_link` permission, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/user_link